# Python Setting Style and Font Size in Excel

Tags: python, excel

Here is my code, please note: am currently learning Python:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
italic24Font = Font(size=24, italic=True)
sheet['A1'].font = italic24Font
sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world!'
wb.save('styled.xlsx')
```

Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#94>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet['A1'].font = italic24Font
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I don't understand why I can't set the attribute. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1:**

What I have tried so far:
using `wb.get_sheet_names()` to check the sheet name and make sure I'm using the correct name. I am in fact using the correct name.

**Edit #2:**

I tried viewing the methods available to my object by doing the following:

```
dir(sheet['A1'].font)
```

The results I got where:

```
['UNDERLINE_DOUBLE', 'UNDERLINE_DOUBLE_ACCOUNTING', 'UNDERLINE_SINGLE', 'UNDERLINE_SINGLE_ACCOUNTING', '__add__', '__base__', '__class__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__fields__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__print__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_key', '_make_key', 'b', 'bold', 'charset', 'color', 'condense', 'copy', 'extend', 'family', 'i', 'italic', 'name', 'outline', 'scheme', 'shadow', 'size', 'spec', 'strike', 'strikethrough', 'sz', 'u', 'underline', 'vertAlign']
```

I tried running this:

```
sheet['A1'].font.size=24
```

But I got this error message:

```
TypeError: cannot set size attribute
```

Interesting.

**Edit #3**:

```
print(sheet['A1'].style.font.size)
11.0
```

But when I try:

```
sheet['A1'].style.font.size=11
```

I get this error message:

> cannot set size attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code exactly as it is. It executed without the AttributeError or any other error for that matter. First, check if you have the right permissions for modifying the settings of `Sheet`. Second, check that your `openpyxl` package is updated to the current version (perhaps the syntax in the older versions may have been different).

In general, AttributeError is raised when you are trying to set a value to an attribute/property that cannot be set because it does not have a setter.